# Set active image in UV Editor for certain object in Blender 2.78

Tags: python, blender

Currently I am writing a script for blender which imports model saved in custom format. My problem is that I want to set active texture in UV Editor using Python. When I hover the button which allows me to select image I want to show in UV Editor, there's no python function name on the tooltip. Is there any way to set another image to each object? When i tried to use [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/active-image-of-uv-image-editor)  the image was present in image editor, but after i select certain object and then i select all his faces, there was no image in the editor.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english. If you don't understand something, just ask me.

Comment: Flip the steps, select all, then choose the image. If there is no uvmap you might need to create a uvmap first. What shading setting? BI will show it if texture solid is on, cycles will only show it in material or texture shading. I think what you are trying to set is only a viewport display, you should just set the material to use the image rather than "assign" it in edit mode.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention - I want to achieve it using Python API.

Comment: Yes, manually you unwrap and then select that active image, use the same order in python. It maybe a matter of your viewport shading settings, try [this example](https://gist.github.com/sambler/9520e5e4f1cf1778d0b72abc4a06cea4).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/active-image-of-uv-image-editor) post on the Blender stack exchange board solved it for me.